# Why does foreach's char loop not function as expected?

Tags: c#, string, foreach, char, indexof

In my foreach loop, char 'c' characterizes each character in the string currentDependency, and if c is '|', then it adds the position of this to List sectionsSpots.  However, it seems to loop through characters that have been already found, which means I probably don't understand exactly how the loop method is working.

In Debug 1, it goes through each of the characters in currentDependency just as expected.  In Debug 2, however, when the if statement passes, it always returns an index of 1, which is correct for the first |, as although the first | has an index of 1, the subsequent |'s should have indexes of 19 and 38.  Why does the .IndexOf(c) return to the first c that passed in the if statement, while the code should actually be measuring characters later in the string?  Thanks in advance!

```
string currentDependency = ">|Policies/Tax/-0.3|Policies/Trade/0.3|Power/Trader:Farmer/0.4";
List<int> sectionSpots = new List<int> { };
    
foreach (char c in currentDependency)//add spots of separations of sections
{
    Debug.Log("CurrentChar: " + c.ToString());//DEBUG 1

    if (c.ToString().Contains("|"))
    {
        sectionsSpots.Add(currentDependency.IndexOf(c));

        Debug.Log("| found in string, index of " + currentDependency.IndexOf(c));//DEBUG 2
    }
}

//Output:
//CurrentChar: >
//CurrentChar: |
//| found in string, index of 1
//CurrentChar: P
//CurrentChar: o
//[...]
//CurrentChar: 3
//CurrentChar: |
//| found in string, index of 1////Why is the "index of 1", rather than of 19, if I already made it through the previous | with an index of 1?
    //[and so on...]
```

Comment: From the MSDN page for [String.IndexOf Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) - `Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence` - You are starting again from the beginning of the string

Comment: if (c =='|') is better condition than if (c.ToString().Contains("|"))

Comment: Take a peek on `string.Split("|")`

Comment: When your code doesnt work as expected, always be sure to check the documentation to be sure your expectations are aligned with reality.   Note that there is an overload ("version") which takes an offset to find the next character from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you are finding the first occurrence (index 2). see: :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8;
The easier way how to achieve your goal is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentDependency.Length; i++)
{
    if (currentDependency[i] == '|')
    {
        sectionsSpots.Add(i);
        Debug.Log("| found in string, index of " + i);//DEBUG 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code as a base, I modified how you call the `IndexOf` function to make use of its other parameters.

```
List<Int32> sectionsSpots = new List<Int32>();
string currentDependency = ">|Policies/Tax/-0.3|Policies/Trade/0.3|Power/Trader:Farmer/0.4";

Int32 startPosition = 0;

foreach (char c in currentDependency)//add spots of separations of sections
{
    Debug.Print("CurrentChar: " + c.ToString());//DEBUG 1

    if (c.Equals('|'))
    {
        Int32 position = currentDependency.IndexOf(c, startPosition);
        sectionsSpots.Add(position);

        Debug.Print("| found in string, index of " + position);//DEBUG 2

        startPosition = position + 1;
    }
}
```

By passing in a `position`, the `IndexOf` function will start looking for the required character from a different starting point, not the very start of the string.